# Is it possible to NOT use Attach and Detach in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I always get messed using attach and detach methods. Is it possible to not use them?

If yes, then why people don't usually use this concept?

I think there is some option with overriding SaveChanges()...

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me. I have not searched the site or google, you may have been able to find the answer but I get why you would ask it..

Comment: because either I don't understand the concept or I am thinking outside of the box.

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn't saying you were wrong posting I was saying I did not understand the downvotes either basically. Did my answer help you understand? If so please mark answer, if not let me know what you are still having trouble with and I can try to clarify. Btw, just added another link that gives you different use cases that may help clarify a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having to attach/detach the entity due to how you are using the context. If you use the context and manipulate the data while inside the context you will not have to worry about the attach/detach.

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
     var item = context.GetItem();
     item.Name = "FooBar";
     context.SaveChange();
}
```

So you will more then likely have to use attach/detach if you are using the repository pattern or any other method of data access where you are pulling the data out of the DAL and working with it in the Business layer or front end. You also do not have to manually detach the object, once you close the connection it becomes a detached object which before saving you just have to reattach to the context.

Here is a repository I really like. It is getting a little bloated now but it gets you working with the data really quickly. I like their "lazy loading" of the dbsets, I myself have stripped out the abstraction of the ORM as I know I want to stick with Entity Framework.

Blog explaining the Repo:
http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/

Actual Repo site:
https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com

Here is a source directly from M$ that should give you a better idea of how/when to reattach.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Here is another link to help that deals directly with different cases and how to attach the entity. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx